# How to override spring boot properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, port

How to override spring boot properties at runtime?

Below command works fine in terminal

```
    mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8081
```

but it's not working in Eclipse

```
    -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8081
```

[image: Runtime Argument]

Comment: Just add `-Dserver.port=8081` instead of `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8081`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. You can configure `server.port=8081` in application.properties file in spring boot application.
2. Configure only `-Dserver.port=8081` in VM arguments in eclipse as displayed in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dserver.port=8081` as vm argument from run configuration of eclipse. It will work